# Can you concatenate a string url in solidity before sending it to a Chainlink APi? I tried with this but it didn't work

Tags: chainlink, string

function requestFirstId( string memory _obid) public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
obj= _obid;

```
    req.add('get', 'string.concat(https://5fes4djdoxic.usemoralis.com:2053/server/functions/getid?_ApplicationId=yourMoralisAppId&objectId=,obj)');
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your codes are like the below:

```
function requestFirstId( string memory _obid) public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector); 
    obj= _obid;
    req.add('get', 
    'string.concat(https://5fes4djdoxic.usemoralis.com:2053/server/functions/getid?_ApplicationId=yourMoralisAppId&objectId=,obj)');
    }
}
```

In the function you are trying to add a "string.concatenate" itself as a string instead of using the function to concatenate a string. In this case, you should concatenate the URL first and then pass the string as the second parameter.

Try to concatenate your url like this:

```
 string url = string.concat('https://5fes4djdoxic.usemoralis.com:2053/server/functions/getid?_ApplicationId=yourMoralisAppId&objectId=', obj);
```

and then pass the `url` to the chainlink request:

```
req.add("get", url);
```